# Search kit display on user dashboard

Tags: searchkit

Is it possible to add a search kit display on the CiviCRM user dashboard page and also filter the result based on the contact record?

Comment: Try looking in the search kit channel in chat. There's a lot of Q&A in there and this sounds familiar.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible with Form Builder. It allows you to show your custom search as a block or a tab in the contact summary or as a dashlet on the dashboard.
And you can also add filters.

I don't know what you mean with 'filter the result based on the contact record' but SK + FB is a must!

Comment: I was asking about user dashboard(/civicrm/user) rather CiviCRM dashboard.

Comment: ah ok! I don't think there's such an output :-/